# Insert dynamic size object at arbitrary position in file

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a binary file with the following structure:

+---------+-------+------+----+-------+
| Header | Obj1 | Obj2 | ... | Index |
+---------+-------+------+----+-------+

The `Index` is a vector of variable size depending on the number of objects and stores the file position for each object. E.g.

```
vector<size_t> index;

index.push_back(ofs.tellp());
write(reinterpret_cast<char *> obj, sizeof(obj));
```

Also the files are pretty big (1Gb+).

I'd like to put the index just after the header, so it's faster to read. Can I do this without having to copy and write all the objects twice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions:

- use a separate file for the index
- move on to a chunk based design

The first one is relatively obvious, so I'll only outline the second one: the problem here is that your index size depends on the number of objects you stream. It need not be so.

A solution would be to skip a definite amount of space (later used for indexing), stream the objects (up to N), record where you are, get back to the index to write it down, and then move on to the next chunk (note: the chunks are not fixed size here).

Example of layout:

```
- Step 1: skip index space and start streaming objects

| Header | <unused space for now> | Obj 1 | Obj 2   | O3 | ... Obj N |


- Step 2: after writing N objects write the index,
          record the offset,
          start a new chunk

| Header | I1 | ... | IN | Offset | Obj 1 | Obj 2   | O3 | ... Obj N | <unused sp
```

Your index is thus built as a linked list of fixed size chunks (N) interleaved in the middle of your storage.

*Note: a third solution would be to use a simple SQLite file and let it index for you...*

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing the file
Calculate how many objects you have.

```
nObjects // Number of objects
```

Then you will need

```
indexSize = nObjects * sizeof(size_t);
```

Start writing your objects at

```
ofs.seekp(indexSize + headerSize)
```

Write all your objects

```
index.push_back(ofs.tellp());
write(reinterpret_cast<char *> obj, sizeof(obj));
```

Move to the start of your index
    ofs.seekp(headerSize);

Write your index

Comment: The problem is that objects are written in real-time from `seekp(sizeof(header))` before the index is created.

Comment: @Marian so you don't know the number of objects before hand?

Comment: No, I don't, otherwise this wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is NO, but if you have low-level file system tools and know how to manipulate your file system of choice you might be able to do this.

Say, you are using old stupid FAT, where the FAT table stores information about  the disk sectors where your file resides, you could then allocate sector for your index, and then modify the FAT table entries related to your file to specify the new order of the sectors on disk for your file, essentially reordering without resaving the whole thing.

How would this work with NTFS, ZFS, etc - I have no idea, but without going into manipulation of the NTFS structures I am pretty sure it's impossible.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Is seeking to the index structure slow? Do you have the position of the index structure within the file before hand, if that's the case can that be changed to instead of have a position, be a name of the "index_structure_file" essentially you would have two files then one with the data and one will be the .idx file making accessing it a snap.

Comment: I have the index position in the header. I'd have to check whether using separate file is faster then `seekg(header.indexPosition)`.

Comment: alternatively you can reserve the buffer for the index in the header big enough that it should hold enough data. Obviously that's a limiting solution, but if buffer is big enough (and you need to look at your files to understand the maximus) it may work pretty well.